# my images are uploading to another folder.. but the names of images are not inserting into images field names in database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i am successfully inserting all details of my form into database using the below code. My images also uploading to my uploads folder but those images names are not inserting into database image fields. Please tell me where i am doing mistake. FYR:I noted that the error was happening before the data posting into database i applied foreach function for image uploading so there something is happening there

```html
//this is my view code
<div class="col-md-10 leftbar">

<?php if($smsg = $this->session->flashdata('smsg')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success dismissible">
        <?= $smsg?>
    </div>
<?php elseif($msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg')):?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger dismissible">
        <?= $msg?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/upro');?>
    <label><h5>product Name:*</h5></label>
        <?php echo form_error('pro_name',"<div class='alert alert-danger'>","</div>");?>
        <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'pro_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'product Name Here','value'=>set_value('pro_name')]);?>
    <label><h5>product Category:*</h5></label>
    <select class="form-control" name='pro_cat'>
        <?php foreach ($cat->result() as $c):?>
        <?php echo '<option value="'.$c->cat_name.'">'.ucfirst($c->cat_name).'</option>';?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select><hr>
    <label><h5>product Parent Category:*</h5></label>
    <select class="form-control" name='pro_pa_cat'>
        <?php foreach ($pa_cat->result() as $pc):?>
        <?php echo '<option value="'.$pc->pa_cat_name.'">'.ucfirst($pc->pa_cat_name).'</option>';?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select><hr>
    <label><h5>product Description:*</h5></label>
 <?php echo form_textarea(['name'=>'pro_desc','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'product Description Here','value'=>set_value('pro_desc')]);?>
    <label><h5>product Color:*</h5></label>
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'pro_color','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'product Color Here','value'=>set_value('pro_color')]);?>
    <label><h5>product Cost:*</h5></label>
<?php echo form_input(['name'=>'pro_cost','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'product Cost Here','value'=>set_value('pro_cost')]);?>
    <label><h5>product Image1:*</h5></label>
<?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'pro_image1']);?>
    <label><h5>product Image2:*</h5></label>
<?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error;?>
<?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'pro_image2']);?>
    <label><h5>product Image3:*</h5></label>
<?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error;?>
<?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'pro_image3']);?>
    <label><h5>product Image4:*</h5></label>
<?php if(isset($upload_error)) echo $upload_error;?>
<?php echo form_upload(['name'=>'pro_image4']);?>
    <label><h5>product Brand:*</h5></label>
    <select class="form-control" name='pro_brand'>
<?php foreach ($brands->result() as $brand):?>
<?php echo '<option value="'.$brand->brand_name.'">'.$brand->brand_name.'</option>';?>
<?php endforeach;?>
    </select><hr>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><hr>
<?php form_close();?>
</div>
```

---

```
//this is my controller vew
public function upro()
{       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_name','Product','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_cat','Categroy','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_pa_cat','Parent','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_desc','Description','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_color','Color','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_cost','Cost','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_brand','Brand','required');

    $expected_files = array('pro_image1', 'pro_image2', 'pro_image3', 'pro_image4');
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($expected_files as $field_name) {
        if (empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name'])) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($field_name, 'Image' . $i, 'required');
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $config = [
            'upload_path' => './uploads',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
        ];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $field_values) {
            if (!in_array($field_name, $expected_files)) {
                continue; // just in case user tries to add more upload fields
            }
            $this->upload->do_upload($field_name);
            $info = $this->upload->data();
            $image_path = $info['raw_name'] . $info['file_ext'];
            $data[$field_values] = $image_path;
        }
        $data= $this->input->post();
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['pro_date'] = $today;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        $this->adata->uproQ($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('smsg', 'Product upload success!');
        return redirect('admin/products');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', validation_errors());
        return redirect('admin/apro');
    }
}
```

---

```
//this is my model
public function uproQ($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('products',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line :

```
$data= $this->input->post();
```

Before the `foreach ($_FILES... )`  so the `$data` variable don't get overwritten.

And change `$data[$field_values]` to `$data[$field_name]`, so it will be like this :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    ...
    $data = $this->input->post();
    foreach ($_FILES as $field_name => $field_values) {
        if (!in_array($field_name, $expected_files)) {
            continue; // just in case user tries to add more upload fields
        }
        $this->upload->do_upload($field_name);
        $info = $this->upload->data();
        $image_path = $info['raw_name'] . $info['file_ext'];
        $data[$field_name] = $image_path; // change this line from using $field_values
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: bro i moved but no change

Comment: Updated my answer, could you try it?

Comment: Dear Hasta Dhana it worked great. Thank you but can you explain me why my code didn't worked and why your code

Comment: `$_FILES` contains arrays of field name (that is `pro_image1, pro_image2, ..`) and each of this array contains arrays of uploaded file information (that is `name, type, size, ..`) so calling `$field_values` is actually calling the file information data instead of the field name data..